# Notice: Undefined index: h in themes/dentario/fw/core/core.wp.php on line 1515

Tags: posts, cache, noindex

I am getting this error on this theme and I am trying to find out if the website even needs this set of code. It is a theme that doesn't seem to have support. I contacted the support team and they acted like it was a different website all together, so I am trying to take the lead from here and see where I need to make changes to keep the theme up to date with professional standards. This is the error I am getting.

```
Notice: Undefined index: h in themes/dentario/fw/core/core.wp.php on line 1515
```

However, when I go to this file, it is fairly long, below is the code that is on this line, before and after.

```
    // Extract gallery, video and audio from full post content
    if (is_array($cached_post)) {
        $post_attachment    = $cached_post['post_attachment'];
    } else {
        $post_attachment = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
    }
    $post_thumb = $post_thumb_url = $post_gallery = $post_video = $post_video_image = $post_audio = $post_audio_image = $post_url = $post_url_target = '';
    if (dentario_substr($opt['layout'], 0, 6)=='single')
        $post_thumb = dentario_get_resized_image_tag($post_id, $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h'], null, false, false, true);
    else if (dentario_substr($opt['layout'], 0, 10)=='attachment')
        $post_thumb = dentario_get_resized_image_tag($post_attachment, $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h'], null, false, false, true);
    else
        $post_thumb = dentario_get_resized_image_tag($post_id, $thumb_sizes['w'], $post_type=='product' && dentario_get_theme_option('crop_product_thumb')=='no' ? null :  $thumb_sizes['h']);
    $post_thumb_url = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_thumb, '<img>', 'src');
    if ($post_format == 'gallery') {
        $post_gallery = dentario_build_gallery_tag(dentario_get_post_gallery($post_content_plain, $post_id, max(2, dentario_get_custom_option('gallery_max_slides'))), $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h_crop'], false, $post_link);
    } else if ($post_format == 'video') {
        $src = '';
        $post_video = dentario_get_post_video($post_content_original, false);
        if ($post_video=='') {
            $src = dentario_get_post_video($post_content_original, true);
        } else {
            if (dentario_substr($post_video, 0, 1)=='[') {
                $src = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_video, '[trx_video]', 'src');
                if (empty($src)) $src = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_video, '[trx_video]', 'url');
                if (empty($src)) $src = dentario_get_post_video($post_video, true);
                $post_video_image = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_video, '[trx_video]', 'image');
                if ($post_video_image > 0) {
                    $attach = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_video_image, 'full' );
                    if (isset($attach[0]) && $attach[0]!='')
                        $post_video_image = $attach[0];
                }
                if (!is_singular() || dentario_storage_get('blog_streampage')) {
                    if (empty($post_video_image))
                        $post_video_image = $post_thumb;
                    if (empty($post_video_image))
                        $post_video_image = dentario_get_video_cover_image($src);
                }
                if (!empty($post_video_image))
                    $post_video_image = dentario_get_resized_image_tag($post_video_image, $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h']);
            } else
                $src = dentario_get_post_video($post_video, true);
        }
        if ($src) {
            $src = dentario_get_video_player_url($src, $post_thumb!='' || $post_video_image!='');
            $post_video = '<video src="'.esc_url($src).'" width="'.esc_attr($thumb_sizes['w']).'" height="'.round($thumb_sizes['w']/16*9).'"></video>';
        }
        if ($post_video!='' && $opt['substitute_video']) {  
            $post_video = dentario_substitute_video($post_video, $thumb_sizes['w'], round($thumb_sizes['w']/16*9), false);  
        }
    } else if ($post_format == 'audio') {
        $src = $data = '';
        $post_audio = dentario_get_post_audio($post_content_original, false);
        if ($post_audio=='') {
            $src = dentario_get_post_audio($post_content_original, true);
        } else {
            if (dentario_substr($post_audio, 0, 1)=='[') {
                $src = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_audio, '[trx_audio]', 'src');
                if (empty($src)) $src = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_audio, '[trx_audio]', 'url');
                if (empty($src)) $src = dentario_get_post_audio($post_audio, true);
                $post_audio_image = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_audio, '[trx_audio]', 'image');
                if ($post_audio_image > 0) {
                    $attach = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_audio_image, 'full' );
                    if (isset($attach[0]) && $attach[0]!='')
                        $post_audio_image = $attach[0];
                }
                if (empty($post_audio_image))
                    $post_audio_image = $post_thumb;
                if ($post_audio_image)
                    $post_audio_image = dentario_get_resized_image_url($post_audio_image, $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h']);
                $post_audio_title  = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_audio, '[trx_audio]', 'title');
                $post_audio_author = dentario_get_tag_attrib($post_audio, '[trx_audio]', 'author');
                $data = ($post_audio_title != ''  ? ' data-title="'.esc_attr($post_audio_title).'"'   : '')
                       .($post_audio_author != '' ? ' data-author="'.esc_attr($post_audio_author).'"' : '')
                       .($post_audio_image != ''  ? ' data-image="'.esc_attr($post_audio_image).'"'   : '');
            } else
                $src = dentario_get_post_audio($post_audio, true);
        }
        if ($src) {
            $post_audio = '<audio class="sc_audio" src="'.esc_url($src).'"'
                . ($data)
                . '></audio>';
        }
        if ($post_audio!='' && $opt['substitute_audio']) {  
            $post_audio = dentario_substitute_audio($post_audio, false);
        }
    }
    if ($post_format == 'image' && !$post_thumb && !is_single()) {
        if (($src = dentario_get_post_image($post_content_original, $post_id))!='')
            $post_thumb = dentario_get_resized_image_tag($src, $thumb_sizes['w'], $thumb_sizes['h_crop']);
    }
    if ($post_format == 'link') {
        $post_url_data = dentario_get_post_link($post_content_original, false);
        $post_url_target = $post_url_data['target'];
    }
```

I guess part of my question is, do even need this code above? I am trying to make the theme lighter, and it seems like a lot of code was put in this theme to cater to everyone. I would like to focus it more on the one business I am working with. Any way I can remove this error? and do I even need this chunk of code above?

Comment: I'm surprised there's no support: it's [still up for sale](https://themeforest.net/item/dentario-dentist-medical-healthcare-theme-/15501504), last updated March. Unless it's so old they're not willing to support your version? (Or somehow someone else has written a theme called dentario too? Looks like it's just Italian for 'dental'.)

Comment: The actual error you've getting is that you have some media without an 'h' attribute for height. You could track down why that's missing for this particular bit of media, and regenerate it or populate it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a PHP `Notice` is just that: a notice. It's not an error. PHP is simply letting you know there is a minor issue with the code. The code will probably still work OK. 98% of site PHP logs will show notices and warnings when debug is enabled. Real errors that crash a site will be logged as `Fatal Error`. See https://www.webdevsplanet.com/post/php-notice-warning-and-error-messages

Second, trying to remove chunks of code from an entire theme is far too complex of a question to ask here. I's something you need to dive into and learn yourself. Start with a simpler theme and see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/

> "...a lot of code was put in this theme to cater to everyone."

Of course it was. Theme designers want to make a theme easy for anyone to use. Why would they want to make it more difficult?

Comment: Well they also want a lot of people to buy it and the more features and options you include in a theme the greater the potential customers it may appeal to.  I find that a lot of the sites our company inherits that use third party commercial themes are only using about 15-20% of what the theme offers and their back-end loads a lot of bloat that the client doesn't actually want or need.  So it's not just about ease of use, but about broadening the potential marketshare.  (Not arguing right or wrong for this - it has its benefits and its detriments.)